# Save axes in GUI as image MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I know there are a lot of answers regarding this issue but I didn’t found any one that help me..
I have a GUI in MATLAB with 2 axes and I want to save separately each axes as .jpeg or any other format.
Any way I have tried – I got either image that including all the GUI or cut figure.
Any idea how can I get 2 good images?

Comment: I have tried to open figure and do copyobj and then saveas, but the image was cut.

Comment: I tried also to do savefig and in this case all the figure was saved, I tried also another options that currently I can't remember, but they didn't help...

Comment: I rolled back your edit. If you go to the length of editing your question, add meaningful information/question in the main question post. Do not just add a line basically saying "_please answer my other question in comment_".

Answer (score 2):

You could loop through all of the axes and call [`getframe`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getframe.html) to get just that axes. You can then save the `cdata` using `imwrite`.

```
% Get a list of all axes in the figure
allax = findall(gcf, 'type', 'axes');

for k = 1:numel(allax)
    % Get the axes as an image
    fr = getframe(allax(k));

    % Save the image
    imwrite(fr.cdata, sprintf('%d.png'));
end
```

If you already have axes handles you can just use those directly

```
fr = getframe(axes2);
imwrite(fr.cdata, 'axes2.png')

fr = getframe(axes1);
imwrite(fr.cdata, 'axes1.png')
```

If you want to include the X and Y axes labels, you could do something like

```
function axes2image(ax, filename)

    hfig = ancestor(ax, 'figure');

    rect = hgconvertunits(hfig, get(ax, 'OuterPosition'), ...
                          get(ax, 'Units'), 'pixels', get(ax, 'Parent'));

    fr = getframe(hfig, rect);
    imwrite(fr.cdata, filename);
end

axes2image(axes2, 'axes2.png')
axes2image(axes1, 'axes1.png')
```

Comment: Thanks, but 2 questions:

Comment: 2. I want to see also the values of X and Y axes. another question - can I define the path to file? (I want it will be user input)

Comment: @erez updated to show how to get the x and y labels if you need those

Comment: I need to go, will be back tomorrow morning to check your solution. Thanks!

Comment: Suever, I tried your solution with axes2image function by using axes2image(handles.axes2, 'axes2.png') and I get this error message: "Error using getframe (line 74)
The specified rectangle is not fully contained within the figure. MATLAB no longer supports this
capability" Any idea what can cause this problem?

Comment: @erez Can you post an image of your figure?